# ADFS 4.0 IDPinitiatedSignOn Page Error: HTTP 400 - Bad Request (Request header too long)

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, adfs

- We are facing an issue with our WHFB enrollment process.
- The ADFS server Windows Intergrated login process is throwing error: 
  ***HTTP 400 - Bad Request (Request header too long).***
- The issue is limited to one user at this point of time
- ADFS IDPinitiatedSignon page working on IE but not on Edge/Google Chrome with the above error when attempting kerberos authentication
- The user is part of 56 groups.
- SAM account name is of 20 characters (Migrated from a separate forest)

Answer (score 1):

Then IE is probably falling back to NTLM, which is bad in itself.

The solution for IIS can be found on:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2020943/http-400-bad-request-request-header-too-long-response-to-http-request

Comment: The nested groups were the culprit here. The token size was as per recommendations from MSFT 48K , but the token size was way above that for delegation purposes. This script helped a lot https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Check-for-MaxTokenSize-520e51e5

Comment: That's a nice script. Glad that you solved it.